# How to add a URL into a dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, url

I'm trying to add a specific URL into a dataFrame in order to export the information into a csv. Every row of this csv has a specific ID added at the end of the URL attached

The URL example would be like this:

```
https://example.navigator.com/index.php?pagina=demoData;ID
```

The problem is that if I convert this into a string and then put into a dataframe column once I export the csv looks like this.

[image]

Few Lines of the CSV:

[image]

It separates in 2 columns the URL.

How can I add the ID properly in order to have the entire URL in one column in the resulting csv?

Thank you

Comment: Can you choose the delimiter? Instead of `;` as a delimiter in the csv file you could use a tab `\t` or a comma `,` - anything that is not in the url

Comment: @FirefightingPhysicist this URL needs to have the ";" at the end in order to access properly to the webpage

Comment: Yes, but does the csv file need the `;` as a delimiter? You could set the delimiter to `\t`.

Comment: could you please copy the first few lines of the csv file and add it to your question? It is propably as @FirefightingPhysicist said an issue with the delimiter.

Comment: If you want to take a minute, read on [How to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You shouldn't post any code or text as image. Just copy the csv and paste it as text into your question. Also important, open your csv data as textfile in an editor and copy the data from there. Then we see which delimiter you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
s = 'https://example.navigator.com/index.php?pagina=demoData;ID'
pd.DataFrame([s,s]).to_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
```

creates

```
;0
0;"https://example.navigator.com/index.php?pagina=demoData;ID"
1;"https://example.navigator.com/index.php?pagina=demoData;ID"
```

If you open it with Excel, you can use the `From text/csv` function in the Tab `Data` and specify the delimiter if you encounter further problems.

Comment: The problem is that the resulting csv should be with ";" as the delimiter

Comment: Not a problem for my pandas version, it just puts the url into quotes. I'll update the answer

Comment: Yes! I finally could add it properly doing as in your last example. Thank you @Firefighting Physicist